# Does business credit score transfer over when you incorporate from a sole proprietorship?

Tags: canada, credit-score, small-business, credit-history, business

I have a newly registered sole-proprietorship in Canada that I am trying to build credit for. If later down the line I decide to incorporate my business, will the business credit score from my sole-proprietorship transfer over to the corporation?

Comment: @SimonB So the history of revenue generated and debt repayment by a sole proprietorship means nothing if you incorporate?

Comment: I've deleted my previous comment as I'm not sure it was useful.